# How to add single quotes to dataset?

Tags: r

A test dataset

```
structure(list(numero_certificado = c("1234", "5678"
), sitio_defuncion = c("HOSPITAL/CLINICA", "HOSPITAL/CLINICA"
), tipo_defuncion = c("NO FETAL", "NO FETAL"), fecha_defuncion = structure(c(1635861000, 
1635874800), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), tipo_documento_fallecido = c("REGISTRO CIVIL", 
"CEDULA DE CIUDADANIA"), documento_fallecido = c("1111", 
"2222")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I would like to be able to

1. Add singles quotes (') to each element of the entire dataset
2. Add singles quotes (') to all elements in specific columns based on index, as some data will be numeric or date and not string

   ```
   structure(list(numero_certificado = c("'1234'", "'5678'"
   ), sitio_defuncion = c("'HOSPITAL/CLINICA'", "'HOSPITAL/CLINICA'"
   ), tipo_defuncion = c("'NO FETAL'", "'NO FETAL'"), fecha_defuncion =  structure(c(1635861000, 
   1635874800), tzone = "", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), tipo_documento_fallecido = c("'REGISTRO CIVIL'", 
   "'CEDULA DE CIUDADANIA'"), documento_fallecido = c("'1111'", 
   "'2222'")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
   "data.frame"))
   ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We may use `sQuote` by looping `across` the columns (`everything()` - if all the columns needs to be changed or for selected columns use one of the `select_helpers` i.e. here if we need to remove the `fecha_defuncion`, prefix with `-`) of the data

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
     mutate(across(-fecha_defuncion, sQuote, FALSE))
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 2 × 6
  numero_certificado sitio_defuncion    tipo_defuncion fecha_defuncion     tipo_documento_fallecido documento_fallecido
  <chr>              <chr>              <chr>          <dttm>              <chr>                    <chr>              
1 '1234'             'HOSPITAL/CLINICA' 'NO FETAL'     2021-11-02 08:50:00 'REGISTRO CIVIL'         '1111'             
2 '5678'             'HOSPITAL/CLINICA' 'NO FETAL'     2021-11-02 12:40:00 'CEDULA DE CIUDADANIA'   '2222'
```

---

Also as @KonradRudolph mentioned in the comments, if the `sQuote` depends on the locale, another option is either `glue` or `paste` or `sprintf`

```
df1 <- df1 %>%
      mutate(across(-fecha_defuncion,  ~sprintf("'%s'", as.character(.))))
```

Comment: thanks. what about the scenario where i would require to omit some columns (like the date `fecha_defuncion` )